# What data-structure should I use for bucket in hash table?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I am trying to create a hash table, in which bucket list can have long length. What data structure should I use in order to keep memory and time optimized?

Comment: If you use an [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) scheme, you don't need a separate data structure.

Comment: This is a broad question and the answer depends on your exact situation.  There are multiple ways to organize your hash table and provide collision resolution. Please narrow down your question.

Comment: Typically a linked list. Or a dynamic list, if you have such a thing. But really, if your buckets contain "long lists," then your hash table is overfull or your hashing function isn't very good.